# Datagridview and Search Button Conversion from String "" to Type Integer is not Valid

Tags: vb.net, string, search, datagridview, integer

I have a search button and when I clicked it, the result shows but it has this message box that says that "Conversion from String "" to Type Integer is not Valid". Here's my code for search:

```
Private Sub btnSearchExpenditure_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearchExpenditure.Click
  Try
    If txtSearchExpenditure.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill up search field!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
        Else
        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()
        RecordCount = modGlobalFunctions.loadDataGrid("SELECT * " & _
                      "FROM bims_expenditure " & _
                      "WHERE type_id='" & TypeId & "' " & _
                      "AND (code LIKE '%" & txtSearchExpenditure.Text & "%' " & _
                      "OR object_name LIKE '%" & txtSearchExpenditure.Text & "%' ) " & _
                      "ORDER BY code ASC", dgvExpenditureItems)
                 If RecordCount = 0 Then
                    txtCodeExpenditure.Clear()
                    txtNameExpenditure.Clear()
                    MsgBox("No records found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                End If
                With dgvExpenditureItems
                    .Font = gridFont.Font
                    .Columns(1).Visible = False
                    .Columns(4).Visible = False
                    .Columns(5).Visible = False
                    .Columns(6).Visible = False
                    .Columns(7).Visible = False

                    .Columns(0).HeaderText = ""
                    .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Code"
                    .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Name"

                    .Columns(0).Width = 0
                    .Columns(2).Width = 150
                    .Columns(3).Width = 540
                End With
                frmMain.recordsLabel.Visible = True
                frmMain.tssRecords.Text = RecordCount
                modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

I don't know what's wrong. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance. God bLess!

Comment: What is the datatype of `type_id` and 'code' columns in `bims_expenditure` SQL table?

Comment: type_id is int while code is varchar...

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert `RecordCount` into `String` like this:

```
frmMain.tssRecords.Text = Convert.ToString(RecordCount)
```

As you said `type_id` columns in `bims_expenditure` table is `INT`, so you need to remove `''` from the value of `type_id` (i.g. your query should be `WHERE type_id=" & TypeId & " "` instead of `WHERE type_id='" & TypeId & "' "`).

Try the following code:

```
Private Sub btnSearchExpenditure_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSearchExpenditure.Click
  Try
    If txtSearchExpenditure.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please fill up search field!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        Exit Sub
        Else
        modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
        modGlobalFunctions.connectDatabase()
        RecordCount = modGlobalFunctions.loadDataGrid("SELECT * " & _
                      "FROM bims_expenditure " & _
                      "WHERE type_id=" & TypeId & " " & _
                      "AND (code LIKE '%" & txtSearchExpenditure.Text & "%' " & _
                      "OR object_name LIKE '%" & txtSearchExpenditure.Text & "%' ) " & _
                      "ORDER BY code ASC", dgvExpenditureItems)
                 If RecordCount = 0 Then
                    txtCodeExpenditure.Clear()
                    txtNameExpenditure.Clear()
                    MsgBox("No records found!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
                End If
                With dgvExpenditureItems
                    .Font = gridFont.Font
                    .Columns(1).Visible = False
                    .Columns(4).Visible = False
                    .Columns(5).Visible = False
                    .Columns(6).Visible = False
                    .Columns(7).Visible = False

                    .Columns(0).HeaderText = ""
                    .Columns(2).HeaderText = "Code"
                    .Columns(3).HeaderText = "Name"

                    .Columns(0).Width = 0
                    .Columns(2).Width = 150
                    .Columns(3).Width = 540
                End With
                frmMain.recordsLabel.Visible = True
                frmMain.tssRecords.Text = Convert.ToString(RecordCount)
                modGlobalFunctions.Connection.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "BIMS", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: @christianuscatholicus As per your comment I have improved the answer try it now.